# Image Rotation - Image cut off

Tags: css

When I rotate an image using rotate(90) the top of the image is cut off, even if the container has overflow: auto.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/2048x1024/000/fff" id="image" class="rotate90" alt="">
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dh0o6vz3/3/

Is there a way to alter the container's css so that it overflows above the image as well as below?

Comment: The fiddle link is broken. Please update your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up having to force a translation, which I guess makes sense.

```
.rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25%);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25%);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25%);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25%);
}
```

This doesn't work in all cases, as the width of the image determines what % translate I need.

But it works well enough for the use cases I have,

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `overflow:visible` instead and you may also change the transform-origin depending on how you want to show the image

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/248x124/000/fff" id="image" class="rotate90" alt="">
</div>
```